# How can I pass a parameter in spark-submit and throw it into a dataframe with Python 2.4?

Tags: python, pyspark, spark-submit, python-2.4

I need to pass a parameter in spark-submit call and assign it in a dataframe with Python 2.4, how can I do it?

````
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import*
from pyspark.sql.types import*
import os, sys
import datetime
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

df_parm = <<parm-spark-submit>>

df_parm.show()
```
````

Comment: Are you certain you need to be using 18 year old Python version?

Comment: @matszwecja yes :(

Comment: same as in python using sys module. In spark submit command you pass args after python file name. " spark-submit PysparkArg.py arg1 arg2 arg3 "